# How to get back terminal at bottom of cloud 9 screen?

Tags: cloud9-ide

While using my personal cloud 9 workspace here: https://c9.io/quinnliu/subtractadd_com

I accidentally deleted the terminal at the bottom of the screen. I have no idea how to get it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can toggle it via menu, view > Console.

Comment: You're awesome. You can also press F6 which is faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly use

```
F6
```

to **toggle the terminal** in **cloud 9** screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the terminal with

```
Ctrl + ~
```

Good to remember when working on a small screen!